# VPC-TRANSIT: Difference between detached VGW and Direct IPSec connection (csr1000v)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cisco, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

Picture worth thousands words So i draw 2 different network diagrams involving the VPC Transit infrastructure on AWS using csr1000v.

[Direct connection between csr1000v and on premise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiO4p.jpg)

[Connection using detached VGW instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cgpd.jpg)

Can anyone tell me if there is a big difference between using one or another schema. The major one I see for myself is that using the detached VGW, i don't have to configure the Cisco routers to connect to on premise network and I get even a configuration file for different on premise router: checkpoint, cisco, etc...

So of course, i'm a big fan of the detached gateway diagram but is there any drawback over the direct ipsec connection csr <-> on-premise ?

Thx a lot

btw: My connection would never exceed 100 Mbps, so relatively small throughput

btw2: The router on premise are not from cisco

Comment: Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/cisco-based-transit-vpc/appendix-d.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One interesting point you have pointed out is that one can use non-cisco routers on-prem and configure CSR.
Apart from that I would say that if you are using a Multi-site on-prem configuration and with a 2 ISP for (active / failover) config; then detached VGW configuration would help.

You can use DMVPN cloud to setup the multi-site config in CSR v1000.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i asked aws customer service and they told me the same, no much difference (not good over bw > 10gbps) the detached vgw is easier to setup obviously. +1 for DMVPN.